# Browning cactus. Cut and repot or wait?

Tags: cactus, repotting

Not sure what type of cactus this is, but it was a grocery store purchase from 2 years ago and has been doing okay until the past 6 months. It sits in a western[image] facing window with about 7 hours of semi direct light.

I’m not sure if I should cut the top and repot, or wait for them to grow larger first? The bottom part is brown, dry and hard to touch. Also... what did I do wrong?